# how prevent bypass cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare

Recently, I noticed that when I set my site's IP with a host domain name header, it easily passes through Cloudflare in Curl's request, but I checked this for other sites, it does not pass and it encounters Cloudflare
Is there a problem with my config server? Or DNS domain settings?
What is the solution?

Comment: *"when I set my site's IP with a host domain name header"* - I'm not totally sure what you mean with this. I can imagine that you mean that you access your site directly by IP address, i.e. `curl -H"Host:example.com" http://ip`.  If you want to restrict such direct access you need to make configure your server to only accept traffic through Cloudflare - see https://serverfault.com/questions/601339/how-do-i-deny-all-requests-not-from-cloudflare

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean
But why can't I access sites that use shared hosting this way?

Comment: Maybe because the sites are setup to prevent this, as described in the link I've provided. Or maybe in some other way. Unfortunately your question offers too few details on what you really did and leaves to much room for speculation on what you might have done, which makes it hard to give useful and correct answers.

Comment: OP, you should configure your firewall on your web server to only allow http and https requests from Cloudflare's IP space.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/225428/does-cloudflare-masking-my-ip-make-my-server-more-secure for more info.

Comment: For example, the code below for the following site deals directly with Cloudflare and we do not have direct access even though non-Cloudflare IPs are not closed. 
$ch  = curl_init( "https://116.202.222.164" );
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
 'Host: anime-list29.site',
));

 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
 $s = curl_exec( $ch );

Comment: Have you consulted CloudFlare's documentation?